# Educational project for Database systems like PintOS?

Tags: database-design, language-agnostic, operating-system, computer-science

[Pintos Project](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/10wi-cs140/pintos/pintos.html) was a very educational experience for me. I like the idea of making a set of test cases pass and working with a live system.

Are there educational projects like this for Database Systems?

Edit: My focus would be to create a dbms engine

Comment: What is your focus exactly: do you want to practice creating your own DBMS or do you want practice setting up and maintaining a database environment?

Comment: @Josien :My focus would be to create a dbms engine

Answer (score 0):

I presume you need a code project (more specifically, a DBMS?) focused on being educational and thus easy to read?

I haven't found anything overly useful on that matter. Usually, most "free" courses and online resourses provide, for example, notes on efficient SQL usage, while others focus on the development of simple (and quite focused) DBMS systems. Take, for example, db-class

There are, more or less, two "schools" of educational/academic DBMS systems:

- The first one, and definitely more popular, is based on Elmasri and Navathe's "Fundamentals of Database Systems", which is considered the "bible" of the field. These courses usually promote the creation of a "stack of components", something like (from low level to high level):

  - Disk Block and Intermediate Memory management
  - Record and Index Management
  - Query parsing, optimization and utilities
  - Views
- The other is based on "The Third Manifestor"'s Tutorial D (Foundation for Future Database Systems, by Date and Darwen). There is a load of such implementations online, for example "Rel", "Dee", "Duro", "MighTyD" etc, maybe worth having a look but not the best resource.

P.S: Both MINIX and PintOS are fine software for teaching OS!

Answer (score 0):

a few years ago [loxim](http://loxim.sourceforge.net/) project has been started. it's experimental semi-structural & object database. it uses fully compositional language SQBL. people were doing their PhD and master thesis developing it. i don't know it is still under development but you can contact the head of the project and try it.

Answer (score -1):

Although it's not a designed as an educational program, getting involved in an open source database would be a decent way to go. There are the big boys, MySQL (http://www.mysql.com/) and PostgreSQL (http://www.postgresql.org/) on the relational side, and then CouchDB (http://couchdb.apache.org/) or MongoDB (http://www.mongodb.org/) for the "NOSQL" side.

Of course, starting small is always best in these endevours, so I would recommend something like SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/).

In fact, if you were ambitious enough, you could design your own educational program around understanding the SQLite design, architecture and code. And then publish it online for others to enjoy and soak up.